# Find a Pull Request on Github where a commit was originally created from the Github API

Tags: git, github, github-api, pull-request

I have a list of commits from the Github API and I want to find a Pull Request on Github where a commit was originally created.

Thank you in advance.

PS: There is a similar post [Find a Pull Request on Github where a commit was originally created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818167/find-a-pull-request-on-github-where-a-commit-was-originally-created/17819027) but I need to get this information from the Github API.

Regards,
Ivan Ivanov