# Find a Pull Request on Bitbucket where a commit was originally created

Tags: git, bitbucket

The same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818167/find-a-pull-request-on-github-where-a-commit-was-originally-created) but for Bitbucket.

If I have a commit, is there any way to figure out what Pull Requests it was in?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819027/3419541

Comment: I did try that.  It didn't work.  It's Github specific as they store pull requests in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was released in version 5.11 of Bitbucket Server, as noted in the [release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-5-11-release-notes-950274914.html).
On Bitbucket, copy the commit hash in the search bar *and wait a couple of seconds for the auto-search to list the commit in the drop down* (that's what was bugging me, I was hitting `Enter` straight away).
By clicking on the commit in the drop-down, you'll get to a page with the diff and various links, among which the PR the commit was in.

There's also a [short video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrBvn0vRvuI) that shows what I just described.