# GitHub Actions: On a push-to-master workflow, how can I get a link to the pull request which was merged?

Tags: github-actions, git-merge, pull-request

I have a GitHub Actions workflow which is triggered only on push to the `master` (aka `main`) branch.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

I only push to `master` via merging GitHub pull requests, not via directly committing changes to `master` and pushing them.

Within the steps of the job in this workflow, I would like to reference the pull request which was merged to lead to the merge commit which was pushed to master.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?

I've tried to find such a reference in the GitHub Actions [`github` context object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context), and the most promising property I found was `github.event`. In my case, this would be the [`push` event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push), but within this event object I can find no property that will lead me to the pull request that *led to* the pushed (merge) commit.

Is there some context or webhook object property I have not discovered which would hold this information? If not, how else can I uncover it? If possible, I would prefer to avoid using 3rd party GitHub actions, from a security perspective.

Comment: You've got the `commit id` (`github.event.commits[0].id`) or `sha` from the push github context, if you add `/commits/<commit-id>` to the repo url, this should redirect you to the PR (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818167/find-a-pull-request-on-github-where-a-commit-was-originally-created)).

Comment: Thank you @GuiFalourd, but I'm trying to link directly to the pull request, to avoid people always having to perform the manual action of navigating from the commit to the PR. A PR link in a GitHub comment is also automatically enriched with the PR name, so you don't even have to follow the link to see what the PR is about; a link to the commit won't give that.

Comment: Would it work to trigger on pull request merges rather than on master? e.g. the opening post here summarizes how to do that: https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359

Answer (score 0):

yes, I found a way

not very pretty, but it works by using [Github's GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql)

this is my get_pr_labels.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
# query github's GraphQL endpoint for pull request labels using one of its commits' SHA

usage () {
  echo "script usage: $(basename $0) -t <token> -u <endpoint URL> -c <commit sha (long or short)> [-h]" >&2
}

while getopts 't:u:c:h' OPTION; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    t) TOKEN="$OPTARG" ;;
    u) URL="$OPTARG" ;;
    c) COMMIT="$OPTARG" ;;
    h) usage; exit 0 ;;
    ?) usage; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

make_query() {
  jq -n --arg query "$(echo """
query {
  repository(owner: \"${GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER}\", name: \"${GITHUB_REPOSITORY/*\//}\") {
    object(expression: \"${COMMIT}\") {
      ... on Commit {
        url
        message
        associatedPullRequests(first: 1) {
          nodes {
            title
            number
            url
            labels(first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
""")" '{query: $query}'
}

# query for all the PRs that added the commit $COMMIT, this should only be triggered when a PR is merged, so we expect only one PR
RESPONSE=$(curl -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -X POST --data "$(make_query)" $URL)
PR=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq '.data.repository.object.associatedPullRequests.nodes[0]') # access the relevant part of the response
LABELS=$(echo $PR | jq '.labels.edges[].node.name') # grab only the names
echo $LABELS # print the labels for the caller
```

And I call it like this from my action (all the environment variables used are availble)

```
PR_LABELS=$(./get_pr_labels.sh -t ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} -u ${GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL} -c ${GITHUB_SHA})
```

I use it to get the labels of the merged PR, but you can use `jq` to get many other parameters. see response [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#pullrequest)

BTW `github.event.pull_request` is only available when the trigger is a pull_request and not a push

Answer (score -2):

This one would give you the pull request link

```
${{ github.event.pull_request._links.html.href }}
```